# Redirect to Zencart showing 403 error

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, zen-cart

I am using both Chrome and Firefox to visit [Zencart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) website but in return I am getting error like this

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem..Any help???

Comment: Still not any answer..Any help....

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would try and help you since no-one else has... though I guess the reason no-one else has is because of so little info in your question. I'll assume this is happening in every browser since it seems to be a server issue. First step in resolving this is to check you have the correct file permissions for the varios directories. Check this guide for details:
http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?51-how-do-i-set-permissions-on-files-folders

If all is OK there, then it is probably one of two things, either a server config issue... do you have an htaccess in the root of your site that is restricting access?

Secondly, it may be a corrupt file in there somewhere, try deleting everything and downloading zen cart again.

You havent said here if this is a new installation, if so the last solution above may be your best option. If not, then I will try to help further if you can post server logs and give some more details of what is happening, what you have done, what kind of server you are hosting on etc.

If its a developed site and you dont have a backup then you sir are a silly bear and should look into some sort of version control such as bitbucket for your future projects.

Finally, although I would post some more details here and try again to get some help, there are not many people looking at zen cart on this site so it may be worth trying the zen cart help forums. http://www.zen-cart.com/forum.php

Hope this helps.